# Will Typescript help me to decide which function gets called?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following directory structure:

```
/Admin/Grid
   abc.ts  // this file contains the one function abc()
   xxx.ts  // this file contains the one function xxx()

/Admin/Dialog
   abc.ts  // this file contains the one function abc()
```

I load both all three javascripts into my browser.

The function xxx() looks like this:

```
function xxx() {
   // do abc
   abc();
}
```

Is there a way using typescript that I can tell the function xxx to execute the function abc that's inside the file in the /Admin/Dialog directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referencing all of these files and your functions are all in the global scope (it looks like they are from your question) then you can call the functions from anywhere.

One benefit of TypeScript that you may want to investigate is the use of modules and classes to encapsulate groups of functions and data, which helps you to organise your program and keep the global scope clear of your own functions and variables.

So going back to your question, if you want two functions with the same name, you can't put them both into the same scope - you need to either:

- rename one
- enclose them in classes / modules
- only include one of the files that contains an abc function

Here is an example based on your question.

```
class OtherClass {
    abc () {

    }
}

class MyClass {
    xxx () {
        var oc = new OtherClass();
        oc.abc();
    }
}

var mc = new MyClass();

mc.xxx();
```

Comment: If possible the second suggestion is I think the most interst to me. If the modules allow me some functionality like I have with C# when I use "using ... " then that would be good. Not sure how to use modules as that's something I have not used so far.

Comment: Yes - modules contain classes, so they are a bit like C# namespaces. Classes contain functions and data just like C# classes. Rather than a using statement, you use a reference comment.

Comment: thanks but could you add to your example. I think you might have missed when editing as your example is just the same as mine. How  would I for example name and use modules? I looked around on stackoverflow and the other answers just confused me. Just noticed you updated. You're using class. Is it different if I use module?

Comment: A module is a group of classes - if you let me know what each function does I can suggest a structure and supply a code example.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer you in JavaScript:

Basically there is no way you can tell xxx() to execute the abc() that inside /Admin/Dialog/abc.ts. This is because when /Admin/Dialog/abc.ts is loaded it override the abc() of /Admin/Grid/abc.ts.

What you can do is something like this:

/Admin/Grid/abc.ts

```
var grid = {
    abc: function() {
        ....
    }
}
```

/Admin/Dialog/abc.ts

```
var dialog= {
    abc: function() {
        ....
    }
}
```

and then in xxx():

```
function xxx() {
   grid.abc();
}
```

This way dialog's abc() will not override grid's abc().

**Edit: In TypeScript:**
/Admin/Grid/abc.ts

```
class Grid {
    abc() {
    }
}
```

/Admin/Dialog/abc.ts

```
class Dialog {
    abc() {
    }
}
```

and then in xxx.ts:

```
class Samantha {
    xxx () {
        var grid = new Grid ();
        grid.abc();
    }
}

var me = new Samantha ();
me .xxx();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is this similar to using Modules?

Comment: This is similar to using classes in TypeScript - the generated JavaScript looks similar to this.

Comment: @Naor - Thanks for your help so far. However you are coding in Javascript and my coding is all done in Typescript. Is there a typescript way to do this. Modules or classes?